# Fire proofing a garage door beam

Tags: drywall, fireproof

The main wood beam above garage door and opener top mount directly above. How or do I need to cover this to pass inspection? It's the front wall and block below. Everything up to it is 5/8 drywall. Very narrow area and top mount opener makes it difficult

Comment: If you [edit] your post to include a picture, you'll probably get better responses.

Comment: How fat of a beam are we talking about here?

Comment: It's a 2x12 doubled over the garage door. So on outside wall. This home inspector had a 104 pg report.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a living space above the beam, then you need to “protect” the beam and “wrapping”the beam with 5/8” gypsum board is one way of doing it.

If it’s the garage attic above the beam, then nothing is required.

See IRC R309.2

Comment: Above garage door? Not really living space. I wrapped center beam. This inspector wants everything covered. I think I may end up buying the fireproof paint